# How can I solve "R studio session aborted, fatal error"?

Tags: r, rstudio

[image]

My rstudio is occuring this error.
"R session aborted": R encountered a fatal error. The session was terminated.

I have tried removing and reinstalling the rstudio app from my mac but it didn't help.

Also, I googled and found out that libraries may occur this error. So, I tried to find my r library path using .libPaths() function in R. However, I could not. Because I can't enter any function because it's keep occuring errors.

Does anybody have same problem?

1. If you have any solution to this "fatal error", please help!
2. If you know how I can find the r library path without using R studio, please share.

Comment: To find out what is your R libraries' path, run `R -q -e ".libPaths()"` at a command prompt. Also, check if you have a file named `.RData` in your working directory. That is the file's full name, not just its extension. That file is where the previous session is saved when you opt to saved it and can cause problems when the session is restored at start up. If you do have that file in your wd, delete it and rerun RStudio.

Comment: deleting .RData file and reinstalling R and Rstudio solved the problem! Thank you so much!

Comment: For mac users:
Make sure you check "hidden files" in your working directory! (you can check your working directory using getwd() function in r)

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
remove.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("dplyr",dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**